# Why a dash appears inside the string?

Tags: c#

I was working on an api function with C#.
If a request is sent from the frontend, the api function receives a dash-included string.

[image]

Here you can see -JJLO.
But when I double click it on the visual studio, it shows only JJLO (which is the correct one).

[image]

What kind of issue is this?
The original one and real one is different.

FYI, Here's the GET method url.

```
http://localhost:54953/api/view?view=Transactions&columns=ID,Access_Write,Access_Delete,AccountSubType,AccountId,AccruedInterest,Commission,ContributionYear,ExchangeFee,ExDate,ImportFileName,ImportTrackingID,IsArchived,IsReversed,Note,ManagedType,Managers,MiscellaneousFee,ModelID,ModelFileAs,OriginalBasis,OriginalBasisDate,PayDate,SecurityId,SecuritySubType,SecurityType,Security_LastPriceDate,Security_Symbol,Security_WebPage,MutualFundFamilyWebPage,Security_LocalCurrency,SettleDate,SpinoffCost,Status,SubType,Status,TCode,AccountInvoiceID,EntityInvoiceID,CalcUnitBalance,Account_FileAs,Account_ID,Account_SubType,Security_FileAs,Security_ID,Security_SubType,TradeDate,ActivityType,SubType,Units,Price,Security_LocalCurrency,Amount,Security_LocalCurrency,Commission,Security_LocalCurrency,CalcUnitBalance&sort=&filter=IsOffset=FALSE AND (TCode="%SPOR%" OR TCode=­"JJLO%" OR TCode="­JJLI%" OR TCode="­JSO%" OR TCode="­JSI%" OR TCode="%SPLIT%" OR TCode="%SPLITSHORT%" OR TCode="%SPOD%" OR TCode="%SPOR%")&rowEnd=20&filters=%7B%7D&cache_breaker=1569863027037
```

Comment: Based on the code you provided (none), I predict that the cause is something in your code. If you'd like to show us a reproducible example, we can help you identify exactly what code is responsible. That would involve posting code as text, in your question, not as a screenshot or in a comment.

Comment: Those screenshots are not readable. way to small.

Comment: How are you observing the first and second screenshots? You say "when I double click it on the visual studio..." What are you double-clicking?

Comment: @JLRishe its a debugging window, so I can edit/view the value in the above "Autos" window by double clicking.

Comment: Have you tried logging the value to the console or trace to see what value is actually logged?

Comment: With the edit, it's more apparent what the actual issue is, so I've removed my duplicate vote and comment. What's unclear is where the second screenshot is coming from. Also, you can help by being clear on what the URL is of the request is.

Comment: Yes, the dash is still logged @JLRishe

Comment: @dkitdev If it's logged, then that means it's actually in the string. I suggest you add a few lines of code to locate that character within the string and determine its character code. It may not be an ordinary hypen and that might explain why it disappears when you switch that box into edit mode. I'd also suggest watching the request in your browser tools and/or Fiddler to see whether the dash shows up there. If it does, then the problem is on the client-side.

Comment: @dkitdev One reason why it is a *very good idea* to give us text instead of screenshots is JLRishe's suggestion that you may have some funny unicode going on there. If you copy the actual string and paste it into your question as text, we can look at what actual characters are really there, instead of idly guessing. Also, no one would have thought you were talking about backslashes.

Comment: @JLRishe I added a GET method url.

Comment: @EdPlunkett added a get method url

Comment: @just-my-name Please take some time to read the question and the comments before offering input.

Comment: @dkitdev When I copy `TCode=­"JJLO%"` out of your question and paste it into a cmd.exe window or Notepad, I see the dash (hypen a.k.a. minus sign (ascii 45), ***not backslash***, for those playing along at home). When I paste it into this edit box or the Visual Studio 2019 editor, I don't -- but if I use the arrow key to move the insertion point back through the text, there is an extra "invisible" character between the "=" and the opening double quotation mark. Same with JJLI%, JSO%, and JSI%, except that in those cases the dash is to the right of the double quote.

Comment: The double quote character is 0x22 (34) and the dash is 0x2d (45), as they should be. I've encountered this before but I'm drawing a bit of a blank. Some exotic unicode character or something (Non-Breaking Space? Invisible Separator?). Where did that URL come from? Can you retype all the string literals that go into assembling it?

Comment: @EdPlunkett awesome!!! heres the original filter string printed by console.log on chrome.
```IsOffset=FALSE AND (TCode="%SPOR%" OR TCode="­JJLO%" OR TCode="­JJLI%" OR TCode="­JSO%" OR TCode="­JSI%" OR TCode="%SPLIT%" OR TCode="%SPLITSHORT%" OR TCode="%SPOD%" OR TCode="%SPOR%")
```

Comment: @dkitdev That one has the sneaky dash inside the quotes. What code is generating this string?

Comment: @EdPlunkett this is really amazing discover. Awesome!!! it comes from the sql server, I am not sure how its set but you saved me. Thank you so much.

Comment: @dkitdev Excellent. So are you able to just retype the DB data? What a shame people downvoted a sensible and non-obvious question. The tiny unreadable screenshots were regrettable, though.

Comment: @EdPlunkett yes, You are really amazing!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200215/discussion-on-question-by-dkitdev-why-a-dash-appears-inside-the-string).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to you pasting the GET URL in your question now, we can now observe what's actually in that string:

[image]

Oddly, we can see that there's a fishy character *before* the quote symbol and it's character code 173 - "soft hyphen". That would sort of explain why we can see it sometimes but not other times.

It's a bit puzzling that it shows *after* the quote symbol in your debugger, but from the comments, it sounds like this is an issue with the value in the database, which you can clean up.